# Query to get child records of given parent id

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, recursive-query

I have a query to find child data from Table2 which having hierarchical data which is defined in other table i.e. TABLE1 in oracle.

TABLE1

```
ID, CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID
1,  1           
2,  2,      1   
3,  3,      2   
4,  4,      3   
5,  5,      4   
6,  6,      4   
7,  7,      4   
8,  8,      5   
9,  9,      5
```

TABLE2

```
NAME,AGE,ID
JJ,22,1
XX,19,2
YY,20,3
KK,21,4
PP,18,5
CC,19,6
DD,22,7
SS,44,8
QQ,33,9
```

When i query for ID 7 the output should

```
NAME,AGE,ID
DD,22,7
```

As there is no child of 7

When  i query 5 then it should show below as 8 & 9 are child of 5

```
NAME,AGE,ID
PP,18,5
SS,44,8
QQ,33,9
```

Please suggest, Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there only one level of parent-child relationships, or does the child need to be checked for its children and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following to handle the general case (i.e. will get not just parents and children, but potentially children-of-children and so on).

```
with thevalues as
(
 SELECT child, parent
 FROM table1 
 START WITH parent=4
 CONNECT BY PRIOR child = parent
)
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE id IN (SELECT child FROM thevalues UNION ALL SELECT parent FROM thevalues)
```

where `parent=4` defines the starting record. [Connect By](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) is used for these hierarchical queries like these.

Although the above also works for the simple case in your example, if you don't care about children-of-children, you might prefer something like

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE id=4
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE id IN
(
 SELECT child
 FROM table1
 WHERE parent=4
)
```

Note that I've hardcoded 4 in two places in this example.

Comment: Yes, I need child of child as well and above one perfectly fetching data as desired

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the immediate children, then an `exists` subquery is sufficient:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where exists (
    select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.child_id = t2.id and 5 in (t1.child_id, t1.parent_id)
)
```

Or:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where t2.id = 5 or exists (
    select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.child_id = t2.id and t1.parent_id = 5
)
```

If, on the other hand, you want all children, regardless of their level, then I would recommend a recursive query:

```
with cte (child_id, parent_id) as (
    select child_id, parent_id from table1 where child_id = 5
    union all
    select t1.child_id, t1.parent_id
    from cte c
    inner join table1 t1 on t1.parent_id = c.child_id
)
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1 from cte c where c.child_id = t2.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this one to find the proper children. Just change the ID you are searching for in the `CONNECT_BY_ROOT (t1.id) = 5` clause from 5 to any id and it should work as expected.

```sql
    SELECT t2.name, t2.age, t1.id
      FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
     WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND CONNECT_BY_ROOT (t1.id) = 5
CONNECT BY PRIOR t1.id = t1.parent_id;
```